# Formule de clôture d'un e-mail (comportant vœux pour Noël et nouvel an)

Tags: traduction, anglais, correspondance

> We thank you very much for your attendance and
>   especially for your interesting contribution and wish you Merry
>   Christmas and a happy and prosperous new year!
>
> Nous vous remercions beaucoup de votre présence et en particulier de
>   votre contribution intéressante et vous souhaitons joyeux Noël et
>   une nouvelle année heureuse et prospère !

De nos jours une telle formule de clôture d'un e-mail est-elle courante en France ou non ?

Comment: Traditionnellement, on ne souhaite ses vœux de nouvelle année qu'à partir de minuit lors du réveillon de la Saint Sylvestre et jusqu'au plus tard fin janvier. Si le mail est envoyé en décembre, l'usage est donc de (ne) souhaiter (que) de bonnes fêtes ou de bonnes fêtes de fin d'année.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On peut souhaiter des [vœux de fin d'année](https://www.lettres-gratuites.com/modele-exemple-textes-voeux-fetes-fin-annee-343.html) ; donc pourquoi ne pas nommer explicitement ces fêtes (**Bonnes fêtes de Noël et de Nouvel An**). Les modèles proposés sont utilisés pour des cartes, mais il n'y a aucun tabou dans le sens de ne pas en faire des textes de conclusion de courriels (e-mails).

Les exemples suivants montrent que l'on peut ajouter aux vœux simples [d'autres formules](https://www.lettres-gratuites.com/modele-exemple-texte-voeux-entreprise-1087.html) telles que des  formules de remerciement, des formules de toutes sortes exprimant les espoirs, les aspirations, et le bonheur que l'on peut avoir ou souhaiter, tout cela sous la forme d'une évaluation annuelle des relations humaines écoulées et à venir.

Néanmoins, il est préférable que l'extension des vœux fassent l'objet d'un envoi qui leur est dédié uniquement, spécialement lorsque les personne ne sont pas des proches ; la pratique de faire passer ce devoir, de toujours considéré comme assez formel, en même temps que des matières professionnelles déplaira souvent, sauf si le ou les récepteurs sont des membres de la famille auxquels on écrit, par exemple, une assez longue lettre ; on peut alors formuler ces vœux n'importe où dans la lettre, bien qu'il soit toujours préférable de leur consacrer un petit paragraphe dans le corps de la lettre plutôt que de les associer à la formule de clôture de la lettre, dans laquelle on peut quand même itérer ces vœux dans une formule brève.